# How to parse parameters using get method with Retrofit?

Tags: android, get, retrofit2

I want to pass 2 parameters and get data through `Retrofit` However i am getting following `Response` in log.

`code...404 message...Not Found body...null`

Here below following code what i am trying..

This is my interface

```
public interface RequestInterface { 
    String NOTIFICATION_URL = "http://xxxxx/api/";  
    @GET("Image/GetNotificationList/{PageNumber}/{PageSize}")
    Call<List<GetNotification>> getNotification(@Path("PageNumber")  String PageNumber, @Path("PageSize") String PageSize); 
}
```

When i call the `RequestInterface`

```
private void notificationJSON() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RequestInterface.NOTIFICATION_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<List<GetNotification>> call = request.getNotification("1","10");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GetNotification>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<GetNotification>> call, Response<List<GetNotification>> response) {
                List<GetNotification> notification_pojo = response.body();
                Log.d("Message", "code..."+response.code() + " message..." + response.message()+" body..."+response.body());
                Log.d("Message pojo", "notification_pojo = " +notification_pojo);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<GetNotification>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("onFailure ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Here is my `Api Response`

```
[  
   {  
      "PageUrl":"ureeee",
      "CircularDetailId":1,
      "Subject":"suBJECT",
      "CircularPath":"/UploadDocument/3phasehindi.pdf",
      "Description":"Description"
   },
   ......
]
```

Api working Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Is the API working in postman?

Comment: @R2R No It's not working.

Comment: Then it's the issue with API.Please check that

Comment: Can you update working screen shot

Comment: @R2R please check I have added screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**  your using `query params` change instead of `Path`

```
 public interface RequestInterface { 

 String NOTIFICATION_URL = "http://xxxxx/api/";  

 @GET("Image/GetNotificationList")
 Call<List<GetNotification>> getNotification(@Query("PageNumber")  String 
     PageNumber, @Query("PageSize") String PageSize); 

 }
```

Comment: Got this Log  onFailure: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: notificationJSON() this is my parsing method, Please tell me what's wrong

Comment: When i debug.. after request.getNotification("1","10"); it goes to onFailure() in call.enqueue()

Comment: Got this... Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162349/discussion-between-vikas-singh-and-r2r).

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
public interface RequestInterface { 
String NOTIFICATION_URL = "http://xxxxx/api/";  
@GET("Image/GetNotificationList")
Call<List<GetNotification>> getNotification(@Query("PageNumber")  String PageNumber, @Query("PageSize") String PageSize); 
}
```

**GetNotification.java**

```
public class GetNotification{

  @SerializedName("PageUrl")
  @Expose
  private String pageUrl;
  @SerializedName("CircularDetailId")
  @Expose
  private Integer circularDetailId;
  @SerializedName("Subject")
  @Expose
  private String subject;
  @SerializedName("CircularPath")
  @Expose
  private String circularPath;
  @SerializedName("Description")
  @Expose
  private String description;

  public String getPageUrl() {
     return pageUrl;
  }

  public void setPageUrl(String pageUrl) {
      this.pageUrl = pageUrl;
  }

  public Integer getCircularDetailId() {
      return circularDetailId;
  }

  public void setCircularDetailId(Integer circularDetailId) {
    this.circularDetailId = circularDetailId;
  }

  public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
  }

  public void setSubject(String subject) {
     this.subject = subject;
  }

  public String getCircularPath() {
     return circularPath;
  }

  public void setCircularPath(String circularPath) {
       this.circularPath = circularPath;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
       return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
      this.description = description;
  }
}
```

Comment: Got this type of Log ..
onFailure: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $